# How to store custom sort order in a web app

Tags: reactjs, firebase, sorting, web, web-applications

I am developing a React Firebase web app, and I want to implement a "custom" sort on top of sorting by name and date. How should I go about storing this "sort" information?

Do developers append a "key" property to the components themselves? How will reordering work then (do i shift every component's key values by 1? That seems inefficient). Or should I do a separate file or database entry that just stores the order as an array of component id keys?

Should all of this be resorted on page load or should I reorganize the data in a way where as soon as I request them they're already sorted?

I've tried adding the order key prop to every item but it seems overly complicated for a simple feature. I haven't had much luck searching this online.

Comment: The question is pretty vague as we don't know what else you want to sort by or your Firebase structure. So for example suppose you want to do a sort by shoe size. If you add a field to your data called `shoe_size` you can then sort by it. Can you clarify what's being asked an include the code you've attempted?

Answer (score 0):

Firestore allows you to `orderBy` and `limit` queries.
You can also specify a cursor to paginate more data on request.
See [This Example](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors#use_a_document_snapshot_to_define_the_query_cursor) in the docs for more info.